# How to develop a schema for the following architecture/ interior design portfolio page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently developing a portfolio/business page for an architecture/ interior design office. I would like to display index pages for each of the 3 types of projects and would like to categorize images within the project. The idea is to be able to click on each of the pills and display a different set of pics on a carousel on the left(See the image link below). I think I would need a projets model as well as a photo model, but I am not sure if I need a project_type model. [Project show page with image carousel on the left and image pills on the right that can change images upon click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5DfG.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Open-ended or opinion questions like yours tend to not be a great fit for StackOverflow, which focuses on specific programming/development questions. Have a read of the guide to asking good quesitons (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then think about how to ask a more specific question that shows what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: how about [enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information that you have provided, I would not create a `ProjectType` model.

Instead, you can have a `PROJECT_TYPES` constant. For example:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    PROJECT_TYPES = [:residential, :business, :industrial]
```

If you decide that you need to store more information that is related to Project Types, then you could create a `ProjectType` model.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you very much. I was not very sure.